# How do I undo the "enable lock & erase" on android device manager?

Tags: android-device-manager

I clicked the "enable lock & erase" button on my mac because my phone has either been lost or stolen by mistake! I don't know how to undo this action because I already have a password so I don't want my phone wiped because I have all my pictures on there! My important pictures are on the sd card but I read somewhere that it wipes the sd card, too. Please help. This is URGENT! : '(

Comment: Once the command has been sent, you can't recall it, as soon as the phone as connectivity it will execute the command.

Answer (score 3):

In your phone, go to the settings, then go to lock screen and security, tap on other security settings, in there you'll find Device administrators, tap on it, then you will find the option "Find My Device" you can turn it off or on.

This settings path may be OEM-specific; other devices may have slightly altered terminology, though Device Administrators is generally well-marked.

Comment: thanks.  mine is "biometrics and security" -> "other security settings" -> "device admin apps" -> "find my device"

Answer (score 1):

If you end up finding your phone, and if it is not turned on, do not turn on! You should immediately remove your SIM card, and move the phone to a location where it has no Internet access. Boot the phone up, backup your data, and let it connect to the Internet, so it can initiate self-wipe...and then you can reinstall all your apps, and restore your data.

Unfortunately, you can't recall the lock&wipe request. You can, however, salvage your data before they are lost forever.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me and below are the steps I took

- Make sure your phone is not connected to the internet (turn off your phone, remove your sim, and or go somewhere you are sure not to connect to any network)
- Power on your phone and go to Settings > Google(under Personal) > Security(under Services) then switch the "Allow remote lock and erase" option to off.

This is the tricky part!

- There's a possibility that this option is on off because you are not connected to any network, connect the phone back and immediately switch back to the security page to turn off the "Allow remote lock and erase" option

since my device is not my actual phone it had no sim card and was turned off at the time i clicked on the "Enable Lock & Erase" option in ADM, so i left my office where it automatically connected to the wifi, turned the device on, confirmed it was not connected to any network, ensured all my back up options were on, went back on the ADM and chose the "Ring" option, my phone then  started ringing (it had automatically connected to a free network in my office building), luckily i was on the security page and noticed the "Allow remote lock and erase" option was turned on (it was on the off side before the device connected to a network). Just to be safe, I am going to disable wifi connectivity and power cycle the device to be sure everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you haven't pressed lock THEN erase, your good. If you can, go to your google settings and disable the remotely wipe data thing ASAP. I would not risk messing around with the wipe data things. I hope your data is saved. I feel bro i almost wiped the data of of mine. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a samsung s6 and really wanted to keep data after clicking lock & erase.
Following the above advice I made sure NOT to allow it to connect to a network (remove sms) or online (disable wi-fi access or keep it off in those places its already connected) but then I got stuck!

I couldnt figure it out but did realise you can call samsung 24/7! 
They got me to delete my google accounts from the phone 
I went on the computer to accounts.samsung.com and logged into my samsung account and was able to delete that too. 
Havent tested it yet but theory is when it connects now it wont erase and I'll be able to get stuff off it.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me.

I accidentally clicked the "Enable Lock & Erase" on ADM. At that time, my phone wasn't connected to the mobile network data / wifi. I searched what to do and found this site. I did go to setting of Google but since I was offline, it didn't show the all the settings.
Then I go to Security Settings of the phone itself under privacy, and clicked the phone administrators. There showed that the activated phone administrator is the "Find my Phone app which I installed from Google Playstore hours before I accidentally clicked the enable lock and erase, not the "Find my Device" which is the one that ADM uses.

So, when I connected to the mobile network data, my files and data wasn't wiped.

I think if this also happened to you, you can go to Setting-Privacy-Security-Phone Admnistrators then uncheck the checkbox of the find my device.

I just don't know if it will still wipe the data if I will go back and make it as the phone administrator again.